# Can I find the line in a bash script a function was called from without a debugger/stacktrace?

Tags: bash, function

I have a simple function that I'll be using heavily in my script. For improved user ability to follow where an error occurs, I'd like to output the line of the script that pulled the function into the warning I'll echo.

Another option might be including the function that called this function as it will typically be called by another function.

Is that something I can do easily within the function?

Comment: Array `BASH_LINENO` might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This echo gives parent file/function/line number :

```
echo "${BASH_SOURCE[1]}:${FUNCNAME[1]}:${BASH_LINENO[0]}"
```

Comment: Excellent! I knew bash must have some variables like that, but I was struggling to come up with the proper search terms.